# Meaning of the word "Dog" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is a conversation between two individuals that I found on Twitter:

> A: Is it necessary  B for several countries to bomb Syria?
>
> B : **Dog** I sure hope so. (In reply to Person A)

Both A & B are from US.

Does the word dog in this sentence mean that B is calling A an unpleasant, contemptible person?

Comment: Funny how less than a hundred years ago, anyone would be greatly insulted to be called a dog.  Today (in urban U.S. sub-culture) it is a term of endearment.  Often spelled "dawg" in this context.  If I can find solid references, I'll replace this with an answer.

Comment: In the specific cited usage, there could be either (or *both*) of two possible senses. Firstly there's the *Wassup, dog?* one, where it's effectively equivalent to ***man*** (or ***mate*** in BrE, ***bud*** in AmE). But it's also used as a kind of "exclamatory oath", as in *Dog! That shit's nasty!* (equivalent to ***Damn!*** or ***Yuck!***). I think that latter usage occurs in [*Platoon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091763/?ref_=nv_sr_1) when one of the GI Joes shoots a Vietcong in the head, but I don't recall the exact words there.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that it's a misprint for "God"?

Comment: @DJClayworth perhaps not even a misprint but rather a euphemistic dodge in deference to a commandment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Online Slang Dictionary is the best source I could find.  Even though I am unsure of its degree of authority, I will try to back it up with my own experiences.

OSD shows there are many uses of [dog as a slang term](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/dog), but does not address the changes in usage over time.

> A friend. Also dawg.
>
> A method of addressing a person, similar to man and dude. Also spelled dawg.

Timeline: Recent (20 years or less).  Most common in U.S. urban culture. Possibly derived from the sense that a family dog is a loyal and beloved pet.  (Source: watching modern popular television and viewing internet memes)  **This is the meaning in your example.**

> An unattractive person.

Timeline: Later half of the 20th century. Most often used by men to refer to women. Considered vulgar.  (source: having once been a shallow, self-absorbed high school student during the 1980s.)

> A morally reprehensible person.

Timeline: Antiquated, seems to have faded early in the 20th century.  Possibly a reference to mangy strays wandering cities. (source:  my memory of discussing Shakespeare's insults in high school)